# Does gzip always need an extension?

Tags: php, file, compression, gzip

I'm compressing a file according to [this site](http://www.swish-db.com/tutorials/view.php/tid/352):

```
$file_to_compress = $dest;
//$gz_file_to_produce = $dest . ".gz";
$gz_file_to_produce = substr($dest, 0, -3) . ".gz";

$data = implode("", file($file_to_compress));
$gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
$fp = fopen($gz_file_to_produce, "w");
fwrite($fp, $gzdata);
fclose($fp);
```

If I use `$gz_file_to_produce = $dest . ".gz";` I get a `filename.db.gz` file with a `filename.db` in it.

If I use `$gz_file_to_produce = substr($dest, 0, -3) . ".gz";`I get a `filename.gz` file. But if I open it the file `filename`has no extension (missing .db).

Does gzip always need an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless your encoder writes the FNAME header, which [`gzencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) doesn't.

When unpacking, if the FNAME header isn't present, the unpacking application by default subtracs the `.gz` extension from the source file to name the destination file, resulting in the bare `filename` in this case.

Comment: How can I write a FNAME header? Is it possible with PHP or do I need a special library?

Comment: @testing [`gzencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) has no filename parameter, but perhaps another library has it. But why would you differ from the de facto standard of using `<filename>.<originalextension>.gz`?

Comment: I got a specification and I have to fulfill it. But I think the specification has to be changed ... Nevertheless, it would be good to know if there is another library out there.

Comment: @testing I don't know one by heart, but there are multiple compression libraries for PHP. Is using `exec()` an option to use a binary from the OS?

Comment: It seems that the specification can be changed. Thanks for your hints!